# How to fix the belowing code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def CostFunction(A):
    return sum(A)

A = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
print CostFunction(A[0:])
```

The answer should be `3`, but there should be something wrong with `A`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't resist -- How loudly is the code bellowing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A[0:]` is a *slice*, not an element:

```
>>> A = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
>>> A[0:]
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

More generally, `A[n:]` returns the elements of `A` from index `n` to the end of the list. See [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) for more details.

I believe you want `A[0]`:

```
>>> A[0]
[1, 1, 1]
```